# javascript: Sortable Search-able table with no paging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sorry for the general question, i am only looking for suggestions.

I need a table (javascript plugin) which is `sortable` and `searchable` and has `no paging` implemented, and the search bar fires up as soon as you start typing.

I am looking for something similar to http://grooveshark.com/#!/album/Halo+LP/5904939

Anybody knows something very similar to that ?

You can see it here more clearly:[image]

Comment: Check out [Datatables](http://datatables.net). It provides pagination but you can switch it off.

Comment: i have seen over 60-70 tables like this. but it looks nothing like what i am looking for if you see the image link i showed

Comment: will this still be sortable even if the table <tr><td> is an <a href> ? do  you know ?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it with `<span>`s at my work. The default sorting mechanism just treat contents of the cell like simple strings in this case. But you should put the Anchor Element inside Table Cell element as in `<tr><td><a hreh="#">...</a></td></tr>`.

Comment: @jibiel i have been working on my css and i almost made it same as in the photo :) datatables is the best actually, thanks a lot

Comment: You realize that display is *not actually a table*? This is more synonymous with a grid control like [the recently abandoned SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki) and [ExtJS's grid control](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example).